# Git ignore same files in all directories

Tags: git, github

I have added to my `.gitignore` file:

```
dwsync.xml
```

However, this doesn't ignore other `dwsync.xml` files in other directories, it only ignores the root directory. How can I solve this?

Comment: It should ignore the file in other directories. What do you mean it's not being ignored? What file-system are you using? What OS?

Comment: I'm using SourceTree on Windows. When changes are made to `dwsync.xml` in other folders, the changes come up on 'Uncommitted Changes'.

Comment: Perhaps your `dwsync.xml` file in other folder uses different case, like `DWSYNC.XML`? I'm not sure how git would behave in such situation. I have already seen problems with using git on Windows related to case insensitivity in file names though.

Answer (score 4):

You say that:

> When changes are made to `dwsync.xml` in other folders, the changes come up on 'Uncommitted Changes'.

This means that the `dwsync.xml` files actually are part of your repository. In this case `.gitignore` has no effect. The files mentioned in `.gitignore` *only* apply to files that are *not* in the repository, and that you don't want shown as "untracked files".

Comment: Indeed. You could make your answer easier to understand if you add that changing the `.gitignore` to ignoring any files already under source control will not affect those files. `git rm --cached filename` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have .gitignore file in your child directories the recursive propagation will not work on that directories. You must add file name/mask explicitly or remove .gitignore from child directories.

Comment: This is false. The presence of a `.gitignore` in a subdirectory does not prevent patterns from a `.gitignore` higher up in the repository tree from being matched.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, Yes, you are right. Seems I missed something.